# Using Heroku database and Shared Preferences for Android Social Networking App

Tags: database, heroku, sharedpreferences, social-networking, android

Hi I am developing a social Networking app. I have an online heroku database where i can push and pull information. According to my research i would need to do this through a web service like REST and then retrieve the any info i want through JSON to my app; in a nut shell. My question is will I need to use android's Shared Preferences if I want to store a user's info like name,password,etc which would obviously be sent to my heroku database anyway. What is the point of Shared Preferences then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few reasons. These would include:

1. Unless you are going to make the user enter all his credentials every time he starts the app, you will need to store some of these locally (you could potentially avoid this by just keying off the device id, but what if the user has multiple devices?)
2. Save bandwidth. Local preferences (what things to show, theme options, which tab to start on), should be stored locally - especially if the user may have multiple devices which use your service. e.g. I might want my tablet to show a different default page on open to my phone.